# ROS Answers SE migration: make3d for ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

anybody knows if there is something like the make3d thing,
http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/

that i thing that it was also used here
[http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/MAV/](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Easaxena/MAV/)

anybody knows another solution for making 2d images to 3d in ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40055/make3d-for-ros/) by [mmmyself](https://answers.ros.org/users/2940/mmmyself/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an open research problem. I do not know any available packages implementing the linked algorithm or any similar algorithms.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0